# Base class pointer not call the derived class method

Tags: c++, oop

The base class pointer does not call the derived class method, while the Base class pointer points to the Derived class object.

```
using namespace std;
class Base
{
    public:
     virtual int f1() {cout<<"Base f1"<<endl;return 0;}

};

class Derived : public Base
{
    public:
    int f1() {cout<<"Derived f1"<<endl;return 0;}
    int f2() {cout<<"Derived f2"<<endl;return 0;}
};

int main() {
    Base* bp2=new Derived();
    bp2->f2();
    return 0;
}
```

The above program gives the error as:

```
main.cpp:28:10: error: ‘class Base’ has no member named ‘f2’; did you mean ‘f1’?
   28 |     bp2->f2();
      |          ^~
      |          f1
```

So when I can use the Base class pointer to call the derived class method.

Comment: Notice that calling `f1` does work.

Comment: calling f1 will work but i can not able to call f2.

Comment: Yes, so we can conclude that the base class has to have the method you want to call.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: If f2 is not called from the base class pointer then what is the use of the base class pointer and/or function f2.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: Then no meaning of inheritance.

Comment: The compiler doesn't really know what `bp2` is pointing at. All it knows is that it's a pointer to `Base` and that `Base` doesn't have a `f2` member function. If you want to call `f2` then you need to *downcast* the pointer yourself to tell the compiler that it's really a `Derived` object.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: right, so every Base class should have the method which is in a derived class, right? it can be pure virtual method or normal method.

Comment: That really depends on the requirements, analysis, and design. Sometimes downcasting is the proper solution. Sometimes it's adding the interface in the base-class. There no one single right or wrong answer.

Answer (score 0):

Result is exactly as expected. The base class has no method f2, and that’s what the compiler tells you.